# "Use UV for mapping" on curve object in Blender 2.82

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, bezier-curves, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to use this option to uv map a curve, but i can't found it anymore in Blender 2.82. I'm using cycles.

has it been removed?

Thank you.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Already default Curve can be UV textured ...

[image]

... converted to Mesh - UV map is generated.

[image]
[image]

[image]

I never used it, so sorry if I misunderstood the reason you asked for.

Comment: It seems now the UVs map are automatically added and updated when the curve is modified. But in previous versions you had to manually check "Use UV for mapping" in the curve settings.